# Calculus and iterated integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, iterated-integrals

Find the volume of the solid from the graph of the equation below.
$$2\sqrt {xy}  $$
and above the square with the vertices (1,1) (1,2) (2,2) (2,1)
 


[image: Graphing the points from the given co-ordinate points]

$$A = \{(x,y): 1 \le x \le 2 , 1 \le y \le 2\}$$
On double integrating the above equation we get the integral as below, I've chosen the strips/arrow parallel to x-axis.

$$\int_1^2\int_1^2(2\sqrt{xy}) dxdy  $$
Could anyone please tell me if the integral has been set up correctly?
[NOTE: I'm supposed to use double integrals only]

Comment: The set up is correct.

Comment: @DougM are we supposed to integrate it just like in the set up or are any other requirements needed for getting the volume?

Comment: You're all good. I recommend approaching it as $2 \int_1^2 \sqrt{x} \ dx \\int_1^2 \sqrt{y}\ dy $.

Comment: Ahh that would work too. I wonder why my professor graded me a zero for this set up  :(

Answer (score 0):

$\int_1^2\int_1^2(2\sqrt{xy}) dxdy\\
\int_1^2\int_1^2(2\sqrt{x}\sqrt {y}) dxdy$

I am breaking up the radical because when we integrate with respect to $x, y$ will be treated as a constant.

$ 
\int_1^2(2 (\frac23)(x)^\frac 32\sqrt {y})|_1^2dy\\
\int_1^2 (\frac43)(2^\frac 32 - 1)\sqrt {y} \ dy\\
$

And now you have your old friend single variable calculus.

Since your region for y does not depend on your region for $x,$ it would be permisslbe to do this.

$2(\int_1^2\sqrt y\ dy)(\int_1^2\sqrt{x}\ dx)\\
2(\int_1^2\sqrt{x}\ dx)^2
$

But until you understand why that works, I don't suggest you get in the habbit of doing that.

Comment: Thanks.. let me try it on paper and see my result.